# Evaluate $\lim_\limits{(x,y)\to (0,0))}\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$$

So the way I approach it, it by the squeeze theorem

$$\left| \frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq \frac{2x^2y}{x^2}=2y$$

So $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left| \frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}2y=0$$

Therefore $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=0$$

But in the answer the author wrote it has a product of two functions, when one is bounded and the other goes to $0$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}x\cdot\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

so $x\to 0$ and $\left| \dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq 1$ why can we say it is bounded by $1$?

Is this is the way? let assume it is bounded by $1$

$$\left| \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right| \leq 1\iff \frac{2|x||y|}{|x^2|+|y^2|}\leq 1 \iff 2|x||y|\leq |x^2|+|y^2|\iff 0\leq|x|^2-2|x||y|+|y|^2\iff 0\leq (|x|-|y|)^2$$

And this is true for all $x,y$ so it is bounded by $1$?

Comment: Which questions remain, in the end?

Comment: @Did if my conclusion is right

Comment: Yes the limit is 0, your approach proves it (once you will have added some missing $|\ |$), and the other one as well, although somewhat more clumsily.

Comment: @gbox squeeze theorem is a very good idea but use it with polar coordinates, in this case it becomes more simple to handle

Comment: ?? Squeeze theorem works quite simply in Cartesian coordinates here.

Comment: @Did Yes of course but in polar coordinates it becomes simpler!

Comment: @gimusi Not really (and even, "really not").

Comment: @Did It's also a matter of opinion but by polar coordinates it becomes a trivial one line proof.

Comment: @gimusi The proof in Cartesian coordinates is even more trivial and shorter: "$|f(x,y)|\leqslant2|y|$, QED".

Comment: @Did of course for this simple example inequality on cartesian form works fine but it also has generated some doubt, as the OP shown; in my opinion polar coordinates is a more effective and clear method also in more general cases; it is convenient to get aware about it

Comment: @gimusi The very last statement in your last comment is true. The rest are opinions, unduly presented as mathematical facts (and which are, in the present case, at best debatable, as we saw).

Comment: Please give feedback on my answer, I don't know why it is seen as unusefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{2}+y^{2}\geq 2|x|\cdot|y|$, so $\left|\dfrac{2x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\leq \dfrac{2|x|^{2}|y|}{2|x|\cdot|y|}=|x|$ for both $x\ne 0,y\ne 0$, but this inequality is still true either $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Now $|x|\rightarrow 0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$, so by Squeeze Theorem, $\dfrac{2x^{2}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$.

Comment: Using the argument that $x^2+y^2\geq x^2$ to decrease the denominator and increase the overall function is a valid practice?

Comment: It depends, but the numerator has something like $x$ and $y$ standalone, so that is the reason why I applied Arithmetic-Geometric inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Note :

$(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2+2ab \ge 0.$

$(a-b)^2 =a^2+b^2 -2ab \ge 0$.

$\rightarrow: $

$a^2+b^2 \ge 2|ab|$, or for  $a^2 +b^2\not =0:$

$1\ge \dfrac{2|ab|}{a^+b^2}.$

Note :
$ a^2+b^2 \not =0 \iff  $

$a \not = 0,$ or $b \not =0.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that by polar coordinates

$$\frac{2x^2y}{x^2+y^2}=2r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\to 0$$

indeed by squeeze theorem

$$-2r \le 2r\cos^2\theta\sin\theta \le 2r $$

Answer (score 0):

- We know that:

$-(x+y)^2 \leq 0 \leq (x - y)^2 \to  -(x^2 + y^2) \leq 2xy \leq (x^2 + y^2) \to -1 \leq  \dfrac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}  \leq 1$

- Thus:

$|\dfrac{2xy}{x^2 + y^2}| \leq 1$

- Hence:

Yes for any value it is bounded. And for $x,y=0$ we use the limit you stated and it is still bounded.

- Note:

You approach is ok but you should not omit abstract in the final stage.